# How to find $\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^2}\,\sin(x) \,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Suppose I have a continuous function $f$ that is always positive over the range of integration and its derivative $f'$. Is there a way to find the following indefinite integral?

$$\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^2}\,\sin(x) \, \mathrm d x$$

Could integration by parts or some clever substitution be used here?

Comment: $$\frac{f'}{f^2} = -\left(\frac{1}{f}\right)'$$ if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$ and let us assume that $f(x)$ is positive and differentiable.

The given integral equals
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int -g'(x)\sin(x)\,dx &\stackrel{\text{IBP}}{=}&C+ g'(x)\cos(x)-\int g''(x)\cos(x)\,dx\\&\stackrel{\text{IBP}}{=}&C+g'(x)\cos(x)-g''(x)\sin(x)+\int g'''(x)\sin(x) \end{eqnarray*}$$
or 
$$ C+g'(x)\cos(x)-g''(x)\sin(x)+g'''(x)\cos(x)-g^{(4)}(x)\sin(x)+\ldots $$
provided that this expression actually makes sense.

Comment: Interesting, is there any understanding about whether or not your expression converges or diverges?

Comment: @CShreve: that depends on the integration range and on the Fourier transform of $g(x)$.

Comment: @JackDAurizio - what would the Fourier transform need to show to indicate that the express converges/diverges? I do know that g(x) is infinitely differentiable, and that the range is some multiple of pi. Lastly, if this is common knowledge of an existing technique I'd be more than happy to look it up/learn about it (you don't have to repeat it). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can also use integration by parts to conclude that

$$\int_a^b \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^2}\,\sin(x) \, \mathrm d x=\int_a^b \frac{1}{f(x)}\,\cos(x) \, \mathrm d x - \left[\frac{\sin(x)}{f(x)}\right]_a^b,$$

so the problem is simplified if $\int\frac{\cos(x)}{f(x)}\,\mathrm dx$ is easier to calculate.